# Recuperar variable enviada en JSON en datatables

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, datatables

Estimados programadores, acudo a ustedes en base al siguiente problema.
Trabajo en un sistema y estoy usando Datatables. Hasta el momento no he tenido mayores problemas, pero ahora estoy con uno que me esta sacando canas verdes.
Tengo en mi Base de Datos mysql, una tabla llamada laboratorios, en donde se guardan registros con los id de campos relacionados. En este caso en particular, se guardan los id de region y ciudad de un laboratorio. Al momento de crear la tabla en datatables, obviamente me genera los id de region y ciudad en pantalla pero necesito obtener estos id en una variable php para consultar en sus respectivas tablas (region y ciudad) los nombres de las mismas y asi reflejarlas en pantalla.
pongo parte de mi codigo en donde hago las llamadas.

Codigo Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#listado').dataTable({

        "ajax": "buscalab.php",

        "columns" : [
        {
            "sClass": "alignRight", 
            "data" : "region" 
        }, {
            "sClass": "alignRight", 
            "data" :  "ciudad" 

        }
```

Codigo php en buscalab.php

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE tipo = 'lab'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
if (!$resultado){
    die("Error");
}else{
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
        $arreglo["data"][]= $data;
    }
    echo json_encode($arreglo);
}

mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Adjunto una imagen de como se ve actualmente
[image: IMAGEN DE VISUALIZACION DE REGISTROS]

Agradezco cualquier ayuda u orientacion al respecto.
Saludos a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Al momento de crear la tabla en datatables, obviamente me genera los id de region y ciudad en pantalla pero necesito obtener estos id en una variable php para consultar en sus respectivas tablas (region y ciudad) los nombres de las mismas y asi reflejarlas en pantalla. pongo parte de mi codigo en donde hago las llamadas.

No es necesario pedir los ids en la consulta para luego pasarlos como condición (`WHERE`) en otras consultas. Lo que necesitas es combinar (`JOIN`) los registros de las tablas utilizando el campo que tengan en común, es decir, la clave primaria y la foránea.
*(Nota: Tambien se pueden unir registros mediante campos no clave).*

```
SELECT clientes.nombre, regiones.nombre AS region, ciudades.nombre AS ciudad, telefono, email
FROM clientes
INNER JOIN regiones ON regiones.id = candidato.id_region
INNER JOIN ciudades ON ciudades.id = ciudades.id_ciudad
WHERE tipo = 'lab'
```

*No te olvides de adaptar la consulta según los nombres de las tablas y de los campos (columnas) de tu base de datos.*

Comment: matias adapte mi consulta a tu propuesta y funciono de maravillas. muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @maha1982 De nada.